# Scope: passing a local variable over to a global variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input, scope, field

I'm experiencing troubles in passing a local variable inside a function over to another global variable, so as to use it somewhere else in the model.

The idea is to have an input field in HTML and typing strings into it. I managed with help to fetch the input string, but I cannot get them outside of the initial function.

#### HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="enter city here">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var place;

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var city = $('input[name=city]').val();
    place = city;
});

console.log(place);
```

If I put the "console.log" right below `place = city`, I then get all the input in the correct fashion. The way the code is now, however, only lends `undefined` in the console.

Comment: value of place changes after submit button is clicked, while console.log is printed when the submit event is binded to the form itself.

Answer (score 5):

Because `submit` has not fired yet. So of course nothing has changed. If you need the value in the function you can write it in as `async` and await a promise that resolves on firing the event.

Comment: It did actually fire. Right after typing and hitting `ENTER` or `SUBMIT` it logs the string, but only if the `console.log` is inside the braces.

Comment: @iBim'sdaMichi: You do not understand the execution flow. `on('submit', ...` only adds a listener that will execute upon firing the event and then immediately executes the code following it. So you subscribe to the event. And then directly log a variable that has not been assigned yet. The code inside the event listener where you assign your variable will only be executed long after the entire code has run.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. Therefore it's necessary to somehow stop the eventlistener for the execution flow to continue to the `console.log` to actually show the global variable?

Comment: Yes, more or less, if you use `async` programming. Essentially, all access has to happen after the event handler has executed. You can register another event and fire it after this handler and your variable will have the value at that point (e.g. add another button with a click listener and click it after the submit).

Comment: It comes down to when and where you want to use that value. If you just need it once you can move all the code directly into the listener and remove the global variable entirely.